# Return class instance with constructor type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, oop

I have an array of classes, in each class, there are different functions and variables. All the classes extend a single Abstraction:

```
export default abstract class Car {
  public abstract name: string;
}
```

Classes like:

```
class Mercedes extends Car {
  public name = 'Mercedes';

  speed() {
    return 70;
  }
}
```

And:

```
class MazdaBusiness extends Car {
  public name = 'Mazda';

  height() {
    return 12;
  }
}
```

And:

```
class MazdaSport extends Car {
  public name = 'Mazda2';

  height() {
    return 14;
  }
}
```

I made a function that looks for a specific car by its name and returns it.

```
Class ParkingLot {
 public cars: Car[];

 constructor () {
    this.cars = [new MazdaBusiness(), new MazdaSport(), new Mercedes()];
 }

public getCar(name) {
        const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) =>
          string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    
        const car = this.cars.find(
          (car) => car.name === capitalizeFirstLetter(name)
        );
    
        return car;
      }
}
```

I'm using TYPESCRIPT, how should I return the instance of the car with the correct Constructor type? For example, if I wrote 'Mercedes' it will return the Mercedes instance with the type Mercedes so I'll have an autocomplete and I'll be able to view all the variables and functions outside of the class.

getCar(“mazda2”) - will return MazdaSport instance with type of MazdaSport instead of Car type.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that shows your intended use?  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9Pdow) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That gets more complicated if `ParkingLot.cars.push(new Ford())` should be allowed.

Comment: @jcalz This is really close to what I wanted. Is there just a way to set the returned car type to be the constructor type but not by name? Right now it is by the name. By name is not what I'm looking for and I want just to make changes on the getCar function and not in the whole class. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, could you rephrase?  The `getCar()` method returns the car by name, so why *wouldn't* you want the type to have to do with the name?  Or what do you mean "the constructor type"?  I mean, my code returns `Mazda` and `Mercedes`, not `"mazda"` or something.  

As for not making the change to the whole class, I'm confused; how does the class know what types of cars exist in `cars` or in the wider universe unless you tell it?  You could make a global "union-of-all-possible-car-types" and maintain it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo53pN) maybe?

Comment: @jcalz The name is used just to find the instance. I would like to have for example 2 Mazda instance and different names. Right now the cars array is Car[] type but Mazda and Mercedes have additional functions and variables. I want that for example on getCar(“mazda2”) it’ll return the instance with the name mazda2 with type of Mazda instead of Car as it does right now. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible if you don't show a [mre] of what you're trying to accomplish.  How is the compiler supposed to know that `"mazda2"` is the name of a `Mazda` and not a `Mercedes` or something else?  How do *I* know that?  Right now the code is showing that every `Mazda` is named `"mazda"`.  If you want something different then please show it

Comment: @jcalz I added the question, getCar(“Mazda2”) will return the new instance MazdaSport with type of MazdaSport instead of Car type. Is it possible?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqkORw) work for your use cases? If so I can write up the answer; if not, let me know what I'm still missing.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, perfect. can you please explain lines 42 and 47 in the answer? And is there a way to make the SpecificCar and SpecificCarName part of the function instead of creating two types?

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance, and I will explain what it's doing, yes.  I don't know why you care about "creating two types" but you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBR2DN) if you must... in my answer I will probably leave it as named types.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. It’ll be great if you could explain what extends, extract and [number] does.

Comment: I reworked my solution a little so I don't need the weird conditional constraint `S extends (Capitalize<S> extends SpecificCarName ? unknown : never) ? S : SpecificCarName)` and instead can just write `S extends AcceptableCarName` where `AcceptableCarName` is a finite union of possible inputs to `getCar()`.  In theory I'm happy to explain that big wacky constraint but in practice I'm tired and it's now out of scope for my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248459/discussion-between-xwizerx-and-jcalz).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, this condition was really weird. Great answer, you explained everything!

Answer (score 4):

First, we need some way for the compiler to match the actual [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of a `Car`'s `name` property to its class.  When you write this:

```
class Mercedes extends Car {
    public name = 'Mercedes'; 
    // (property) Mercedes.name: string
}
```

the compiler infers that `name` is of type `string`, which is too wide for your purposes.  For all the compiler knows or cares, someone could write `let c = new Mercedes(); c.name = "Fiat";`, so it wouldn't have any reason to suspect that the string `"Mercedes"` has anything to do with the type `Mercedes`.

One way to address this is to mark `name` as [a `readonly` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties).  Then the compiler will infer a narrower type:

```
class Mercedes extends Car {
    public readonly name = 'Mercedes'; 
    //     ^^^^^^^^
    // (property) Mercedes.name: "Mercedes"
}
```

Now the `name` property of every `Mercedes` is known by the compiler to be `"Mercedes"`.  So at the outset you should probably mark each class's `name` field as `readonly`.

---

Once you've done that, we need to give `ParkingLot` enough type information for `getCar()` to be implementable.  In your code you [declared the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) of the `cars` field to be `Car[]`.  Again, this is too wide for your purposes.  It is important that the compiler know which subclasses of `Car` are members of `cars`.

The easiest way to do this is not to annotate the type of `cars` at all, and just let the compiler [infer its type from the value assigned in the constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#class-property-inference-from-constructors):

```
class ParkingLot {
    public cars;
    // (property) ParkingLot.cars: (Mercedes | MazdaBusiness | MazdaSport)[]

    constructor() {
        this.cars = [new MazdaBusiness(), new MazdaSport(), new Mercedes()];        
    }
}
```

You can see from above that the inferred type of `cars` is `(Mercedes | MazdaBusiness | MazdaSport)`, which is more specific than `Car[]`. The compiler now knows that each element of `cars` is in the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Mercedes | MazdaBusiness | MazdaSport`, which is necessary if there's any hope of getting the compiler to know what `getCar()` will return.

Before we proceed I'm going to define a few helper types:

```
type SpecificCar = ParkingLot['cars'][number];
// type SpecificCar = Mercedes | MazdaBusiness | MazdaSport
```

The type `SpecificCar` is the element type of the `cars` array: the union of possible types that can come out of `getCar()`.  This is computed via two [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html): The type `ParkingLot['cars']` is the type you get when you index into a `ParkingLot` object with a key of type `"cars"`; that is, it's the type of the `cars` property of `ParkingLot`, which is `(Mercedes | MazdaBusiness | MazdaSport)[]`, an array type.  And `ParkingLot['cars'][number]` is the type you get when you index into that array type with a numeric index; that is, it's the type of the elements of the `cars` array, which is `Mercedes | MazdaBusiness | MazdaSport`.

```
type SpecificCarName = SpecificCar['name']
// type SpecificCarName = "Mercedes" | "Mazda" | "Mazda2"
```

The `SpecificCarName` type is the union of `name` properties corresponding to the subclasses of `Car` in `SpecificCar` (which is the type you get when indexing into a value of type `SpecificCar` with a key of type `"name"`).  And finally:

```
type AcceptableCarName = SpecificCarName | Uncapitalize<SpecificCarName>;
// type AcceptableCarName = "Mercedes" | "Mazda" | 
//   "Mazda2" | "mercedes" | "mazda" | "mazda2"
```

These are the acceptable inputs to `getCar()`; those that either exactly match the `name` property of the elements of the `cars` array, or are what you get when you lowercase the first character of that property value, using [the `Uncapitalize<T>` intrinsic string manipulation type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uncapitalizestringtype).

---

Now we can start to write `getCar()`.  First let me describe the call signature:

```
public getCar<S extends AcceptableCarName>(
  name: S
): Extract<SpecificCar, { name: Capitalize<S> }>;
```

This method is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `S`, the type of the value you pass in for the `name` argument.  It is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `AcceptableCarName`, so it will only allow you to pass in "good" `name` parameters.

The return type is `Extract<SpecificCar, {name: Capitalize<S> }>`, using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  The idea is that we are filtering the `SpecificCar` union to just the member (or members) assignable to `{name: Capitalize<S> }>`, where [the intrinsic string manipulation type `Capitalize<S>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype) corresponds to the string `S` where the first character has been converted to upper case.

Which means: if `name` is of type `S`, then the return type of `getCar()` will be any elements of the `SpecificCar` union whose `name` property is `S` with the first character uppercased... which is what the implementation of your function does.

That yields this behavior:

```
const lot = new ParkingLot();

const mazd = lot.getCar("mazda"); 
// const mazd: MazdaBusiness
const merc = lot.getCar("mercedes"); 
// const merc: Mercedes
const m2 = lot.getCar("mazda2"); 
// const m2: MazdaSport

const nothing = lot.getCar("yugo"); // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~~~~
// error! Argument of type '"yugo"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type AcceptableCarName
// const nothing: never
```

That's all great.  When you pass good values into `getCar()`, the compiler figures out which specific type of `SpecificCar` comes out.  `lot.getCar("mazda")` is of type `MazdaBusiness`, for example.  And when you pass bad values in, there's a compiler error to warn you.  (The return type in such cases is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), which is probably accurate, since the implementation is unlikely to be able to return anything at all in such situations.)

---

And now for the actual implementation:

```
public getCar<S extends AcceptableCarName>(
    name: S
) {
    const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string: string) =>
        string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);

    const car = this.cars.find(
        (car): car is Extract<
            SpecificCar, { name: Capitalize<S> }
        > => car.name === capitalizeFirstLetter(name)
    );

    if (!car) throw new Error("SOMEONE STOLE MY CAR");

    return car;
}
```

This turns out to have the same call signature.  I've annotated the callback to [the `find()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) so that the compiler recognizes it as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  By returning a value of type `car is Extract<SpecificCar, {name: Capitalize<S> }>`, I'm saying that if body `car.name === capitalizeFirstLetter(name)` evaluates to `true`, then `car` is known to be of the specific car type we're trying to return.

After the call to `this.cars.find()`, the type of `car` is `Extract<SpecificCar, {name: Capitalize<S> }> | undefined` because, as far as the compiler knows, the `find()` method might not find anything.  I deal with that with the added `if (!car) throw ...` line before `return car`.  That convinces the compiler that `car` will not be `undefined` if the method returns, and so the return type is the desired type without `undefined`.

---

So there you go.  As a recap, we had to

- strongly type the `name` property of `Car` subclasses as string literal types,
- strongly type the `cars` property of `ParkingLot`,
- give `getCar()` a suitable generic call signature, and then
- implement the function to match that signature

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwsKCDeAUAsQgA4CuIyAlrAqJDPAlAKbAAmA9gHbICeCHsAC2rAFwJG1HgHMA3AQC+BAijQYAsqyixWHVhlYAPCKx4cM2XIRJlKNOm068BQ0awQBeBAHJtuvqGvvIIAPRhCAA8ALQxCCLAANaeEAAW1Bg0ZjDIbhD8pPpEJBEIABSkUFxFUAUAlAgBegZgAHTCYpIARM1BYN0lxGBF+uWNtnYkbBDkUDwIAOwADIp2Kiqq6uhNwABeHMAAQuRgMoZGpuaWWDj4Q-ZUtCzs3HyCnZ4+-vuHIeGRWLxRIpBDpTIIbI6YB5QQFIocVR2NKsaiyNIQcb3KbTVizeYIACMACY1iQNltUDtNL9gABlUhcOoIExmCxWO6TYgUJ5OV6uD4ebx+GkHYDE-5lIEJZKpDJZag5GH5QrFB4otEYrFcqYzOYLQkAFjJxApqjUVIwAAUcEkZLIADJcRA6nmOJA4MAmgEVKo1HQNBA2qB2uROiBtWCeyTlPqtBAAH12YpOZx4F0TycODKZEHqAG0ALpIkiwXiMcjwJnah52cHtKNQDA+fPpgDuWeOp3O6HGABohKwO6Ls4y6v3B8OdC1DONC97NnY3c9ZHjrFE6SyruyEABBWB6UgQUDIVjWAByHgAfOVayRPpI6Q8JnfiGWeJAPaRFTDqHtWAAYtQTYQA6eI5MK5TSHIkjQbIjReFer5THBkZpDgu6Yss9RtBAXAAKqkLU2BgKwWIANRSNA9ptGAjhkYS9SKMh76fo2wr1pGnptAAZjIHC3jiOLlI29SSOxEIAKKmEwEBRMhQkIAyrCwNQfGwNYA54O4XS3N+x40P+G5XggKiKXYJmIR6UAdEKXj2V+P6GYBwGQGBEA5OUnz1MhTEljiakVAAhKJYJpNUHbtggklQNUUDlN0dIAPKaJJSXnpJSkACpJQ6mWaAAmlgu4AErdH5yF6gSjYLsoBDwp4ymqep1jCsGoaOs6+a+I2YC+IWrbkCIIA6POBBlA1SlFM1tCtT4caGJmI5dmmGZJstOZ1PVqpTSpamzTgl5iMKTX7RpODdZ8-XjZEk2nS1h12QgvTTv03SZr0tLvUmn1isSgyTfuh7HlQZ6PcdPj3QdUBHZ4Sb4TwUb6b+RlQ+dMPXooE07UDrBHieYMYxDz0LQMH3Ld9JO0v9H1iIErSU90iRiozzOHP9WzlogyDOsKUXtfa4bjGoXMygcwo8xGq4QNYCVs8A5WhGUrGIGzkjLamPZgCLH5cKebQ87I5Rs20GropiOF4UBxhjMS9SNGU3Qkm0yzLIMKsJNOEvOm00uy0zr0M0xPoe3TsDq4Hhg62AeusAbXBG2HtGjAJltcNbtv28QjsrC7bucx+qvEt7UtrjgcvU4rIeiyIxLq7Sm0QOaHs8M6GRyCXvtl-F3T8OQshcFXZSALwbgClO0pKVpRl2W5flRWYKVN0IHEK+r2v69xCZAB+O+70vOhxUFe5QLIQ3mIgXA8WCO2+L3-eD74CAQq3iAaGiwig2CXBkDgHgQZf18ih7gPHjEGp4LweCXi3Nu9pJDpgAG46HNAQIAA)

Comment: This is crazy man.... I've been ignoring type checking on this kind of use-cases.
Thanks for your contribution 

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a return type of *Car*.

```js
public getCar(name): Car {
    ...
}
```

And then if you need to get a constructor you can access it through `<your-instance>.constructor` just like in plain JS.

In theory you could have also used union type - however that would have been tedious and impractial since you would have had to include all subclasses of *Car* manually like `Mercedes | Mazda`.

Comment: The Car type isn't relevant for me, I'm looking for the other types (Mercedes | Mazda)